# SAPUI5, Stored Data from an API into AN JSONModel, can only be circumstantialy accessed

Tags: javascript, arrays, sapui5

as the Title states, the Data that was stored from an API in a JSONModel, can only be circumstancialy accessed.

In the code, the only time when an Object with the Data(that i was looking for), was given out, was during console.log(third Row).

When i tried to define a list/b so the content of the Object inside the function can be pushed into this list, variable

Variable B/List didnt give out the Object only an Empty Constructor

The only time it gives out an Object is only in the console.log - Row

How can i solve this Problem?

Best Regards,
Roman

1.Tried putting whole

```
oModel.attachRequestCompleted(function(){
                oModel.getData()
}
```

- as a variable, as you can see without console.log.

so that i can be used outside of the function.

**Result**: Constructor without any Data not an Object, with console.log - doesn't work also

2. Defining a list/variable(b) and pushing the whole object i.e. oModel.getData() - into it

**Result**: a Constructor without any data

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
var b;
var list = []                
oModel.attachRequestCompleted(function() {

           console.log(oModel.getData());

           b = oModel.getData();
           list.push(oModel.getData();
});

console.log(b);   
console.log(list);

oModel.loadData("https://feiertage-api.de/api/?jahr=2014");

Expected results
1. Variable with the Object, outside of the function

Actual results
1. Empty Constructor of little use
```